# UTF-32be error WordPress

Tags: plugins, php, errors, encoding

I am getting a character encoding error

> Fatal error: Could not convert the script from the detected encoding "UTF-32BE" to a compatible encoding in /home/coin/web/***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ol_scrapes/classes/class-ol-scrapes.php(3594) : runtime-created function(1) : runtime-created function(1) : runtime-created function on line 1

in WordPress

Can someone tell me, how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

This means the file is encoded in [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32), an encoding that PHP doesn't support.

Open the file in a text editor that does support it, and convert it to **UTF-8 without BOM**. You should also check the other files in that plugin and contact the author to make them aware of the problem.